# Haskell Forall error illegal symbol

Tags: haskell

I have been getting this error in my program:

```
Illegal symbol '.' in type
    Perhaps you intended to use RankNTypes or a similar language
    extension to enable explicit-forall syntax: forall <tvs>. <type>
```

My program is:

```
ex31 :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
ex31 [] = []
ex31 (h:t) = complementar 0 (h:t)

complementar :: forall a. Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
complementar _ [] = []
complementar x (h:t) = if (x / 2) == div x 2
                       then complementar (x+1) t
                       else h : complementar (x+1) t
```

Comment: Have you tried following the advice? :)   Add `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` to the top of the file.

Comment: For this specific case, you can simply remove `forall a. `. Enabling the `ScopedTypeVariables` also works. (There are other errors, though, like using `/2` on an `Int`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard Haskell doesn't support the `forall` syntax you're trying to use.  In order to use it, you need to enable a language extension, such as `RankNTypes`.  There are several ways to enable these extensions, but the most straightforward is to add a line at the top of a source file like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
```

In GHCi at the interactive prompt, you can do:

```
> set -XRankNTypes
```

In this case, however, I'm not sure why you've written:

```
complementar :: forall a. Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

since it's equivalent to writing:

```
complementar :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

which is standard Haskell syntax and doesn't require any extension.

The other issue with your program is that the check for whether `x` is even or not (i.e., the `(x / 2) == div x 2` expression) won't work in Haskell.  The division operator "`/`" doesn't work with integers, so you'd have to convert the `x` to a floating point first.

That would work in this case, but generally tests based on equality of floating point numbers are tricky and best avoided.  A more standard way of checking if one integer is divisible by another is to see if the remainder after integer division is zero, which you can do using the `rem` function:

```
> 10 `rem` 2 == 0
True
> 7 `rem` 2 == 0
False
>
```

(If you have to deal with negative numbers, you might need to look into the difference between `rem` and `mod`, though.)

In this particular case, there's a library function you can use:

```
> even 10
True
> even 7
False
>
```